# Copying a value in a pattern match without owning it

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am going through the [too-many-linked-lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-pop.html) tutorial, looking to implement a simple linked list:

```
use std::mem;

struct Node{
    elem: i32,
    next : Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

pub struct List{
    head: Link,
}

impl List{
    pub fn pop_node(&mut self) -> Link{
        let node = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);
        match node {
            Link::More(nd) => {self.head= nd.next;}
            _ => ()
        };
        node
    }
}
```

The `pop_node` function is to return the node at the head of the list. However it
does not seem to compile complaining that I moved the variable `node` while accessing `nd`. Is there a way I can pass the bound variable in a pattern match without owning it?

This is the error I see:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `node`
  --> src/first.rs:34:9
   |
31 |             Link::More(nd) => {self.head= nd.next;}
   |                        -- value partially moved here
...
34 |         node
   |         ^^^^ value used here after partial move
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because value has type `Box<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: borrow this field in the pattern to avoid moving `node.0`
   |
31 |             Link::More(ref nd) => {self.head= nd.next;}
   |                        +++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Any idea what I should be doing here? (I tried things like unpacking the node struct but they didn't seem to work.)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is fundamentally against Rust's borrow rules: your are trying to pop the head of the list **including its link to the next node**, while still keeping the next node. This means that you would have two pointers the next node on the list. This is an issue because `Box` is an "owned" pointer, in the sense that it's a pointer that also owns the pointed data.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there something else I can use in place of `Box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you're performing this kind of operation, you want the actual element (the `i32` here), so maybe return `Option<i32>` instead -- `None` would indicate that the list was empty.  Doing this is much simpler than what you're trying to do.  Within the `match` you can just return `nd.elem`.

```
impl List{
    pub fn pop_node(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        let node = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);
        match node {
            Link::More(nd) => {
                self.head = nd.next;
                Some(nd.elem)
            }
            Link::Empty => None
        }
    }
}
```

Note this operation should be called `shift_node` (`pop_node` would be expected to remove the *last* node, not the first).

I'd also consider replacing your `Link` type with `Option<Box<Node>>`. Then you can use utilities already present on `Option`. For example, your `mem::replace()` call could be replaced with `self.head.take()` and then you're just mapping the result.  You can keep the `Link` name by making it an alias (`type Link = Option<Box<Node>>;`).

```
use std::mem;

struct Node{
    elem: i32,
    next: Link,
}

type Link = Option<Box<Node>>;

pub struct List {
    head: Link,
}

impl List{
    pub fn pop_node(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.head.take().map(|nd| {
            self.head = nd.next;
            nd.elem
        })
    }
}
```